# CSS body element width not working

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Some content</p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 470px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tsLu98tL/

Why does this not center all the way and why does the color expand to the whole page and not 470px?

Comment: Body really can't be used as if it were a DIV or something.  If you want something centered, you should create a DIV for it and style it with margin:5px auto; (or something).  That will force the left and right margins to be automatic.

Comment: Body will not take a width.  Use a div inside the body tag, instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The body actually *is* taking that width, and it *is* centering. It's just a CSS quirk that makes the background occupy the whole page rather than the space actually occupied by the body element.

A way to fix this is to include a `background` property on the `html` tag.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/purmou/tsLu98tL/1/) an example.

However, as mentioned by others, this probably isn't something you want to do. It's better to add a `div` *within* the body and style that.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! I will use a div. I just wanted to know why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

When the `<html>` element has no specified background the body background will cover the page. If the html element *does* have a background specified on it, the body background will behave like any other element.

From the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html):

> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. For
>   documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for
>   'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas

So essentially your code is fine and the content *is* centered, but the background you specified on the body is being applied to the `<html>` as well. You can see the difference when you give the `<html>` element a white background:

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tsLu98tL/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is applying those property on the whole page.

Maybe you were looking for this:

```
p { //body changed to p
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 470px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

[Here is the updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsLu98tL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a width on body, it's defined by the browser size.  Edit your html to contain inner content, and it will work fine.

[This:](https://jsfiddle.net/tsLu98tL/2/)

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're treating the `body` like a `<div>` element. This is causing the text to be centered. Instead enclose your

`<p>Some content</p>` inside a `<div>` and maybe give it a `class`

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="name"
       <p>Some content</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.name{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 470px;
    background-color: cyan;
    text-align: center;
}
```

if you don't want to use a `class` or `id` or `<div>` you can simple change all `<p>` to that css

```
CSS:

p{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 470px;
    background-color: cyan;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Into browser, the `<body></body>` represent the main container and width is referred to browser. 
If you want center all content into body can simply try something so:

```
body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: cyan;
}

<body>
  <p> Content </p>
</body>
```

I prefer include the content into `<div></div>`.